# sox mix nested scripts on amazon ec2 rhel linux

Tags: bash, script, amazon-ec2, redhat-enterprise-linux, sox

I'm trying to use "sox" to mix some audio files.

The command works great on my Mac terminal

```
sox -m audio.wav "| sox upload.wav -p trim 2 1 pad 6" final.wav
```

This mixes (not concatenate) audio.wav and a section of upload.wav from the 2nd second to the 3rd second and adds 6 seconds of padding in the front, and outputs to final.wav

Now the problem is, the SAME EXACT command does NOT work my Amazon EC2 RHEL box. (sox is installed correctly). I get the following error

```
sox soxio: Can't open input file `| sox upload.wav -p trim 2 2 pad 6': No such file or directory
```

For some reason RedHat doesn't like the double quotes. Even though it is documented to be used this way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the file is not present in the directory you are trying to run this from. Or see the file permissions of the audio file. And set it to 755 or 777. I'd suggest using full file names like this - /var/www/audio/test.wav